# Docker container stopped running and completely disappeared

Tags: docker

I run my Docker image in the following manner:

```
docker run --privileged --name openvas --rm -dti -p 9392:9392 <image_name>
```

The container runs fine for about 8-12 minutes and then it just completely disappears. `docker ps -a` doesn't show the container running any more.

I haven't been able to find any "docker logs" other than container logs, which in my case no longer exists since the container is gone.

When just preparing the running processes that contain "docker" in it, here's what I can see:

```
root      105873  3.5  0.6 1715848 24860 ?       Ssl   2022 2149:08 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
root     3730648  0.0  0.0 1222272 1576 ?        Sl   22:26   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 9392 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 9392
root     3730656  0.0  0.0 1148224 1524 ?        Sl   22:26   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 9392 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 9392
root     3732368  0.0  0.0   8624  1964 pts/1    S+   22:33   0:00 grep --color=auto -i docker

root      105873  3.5  0.7 1715848 29228 ?       Ssl   2022 2149:09 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock
root     3730648  0.0  0.0 1222272 1576 ?        Sl   22:26   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip 0.0.0.0 -host-port 9392 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 9392
root     3730656  0.0  0.0 1148224 1524 ?        Sl   22:26   0:00 /usr/bin/docker-proxy -proto tcp -host-ip :: -host-port 9392 -container-ip 172.17.0.2 -container-port 9392
root     3732370  0.0  0.1 1081712 5872 ?        Dl   22:33   0:00 runc --root /var/run/docker/runtime-runc/moby --log /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/2692e34b79618056c6896af5d2da9f539c210c739ef7bae7420862e46e695ab0/log.json --log-format json --systemd-cgroup delete 2692e34b79618056c6896af5d2da9f539c210c739ef7bae7420862e46e695ab0
root     3732372  0.0  0.0   8624  1948 pts/1    S+   22:33   0:00 grep --color=auto -i docker
```

While running this in a loop, the first part of the output above showed pretty consistently. When the container decided to disappear, I noticed the other output that contained logs. However, the file doesn't exist:

```
# cat /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/2692e34b79618056c6896af5d2da9f539c210c739ef7bae7420862e46e695ab0/log.json
cat: /run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/2692e34b79618056c6896af5d2da9f539c210c739ef7bae7420862e46e695ab0/log.json: No such file or directory
```

Is there a general Docker log file that I can check to see why this container continues to crash? I've tried replicating this on other systems with the same container and had no issues. So I can't tell if it's crashing because of memory or anything at the moment.

Comment: Do you have your image's Dockerfile or any other source code that would be required to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Just the docker image itself, but I'm unable to reproduce the issue on other systems. I was hoping that there would be some sort of syslogs from docker that would help in this case.

Comment: You could try running a custom command with `docker run`, which effectively does nothing (like `bash`, which just creates a shell). Then you could shell in, run the actual image command, and see what makes it crash. Consider setting up an on-host volume for the logs for that process too, so you can have a permanent record of the issue if the container stops prematurely.

Answer (score 0):

The `--rm` option is used to delete the container when it exits or stops for any reason:

```
$ docker run --help
...
      --rm                             Automatically remove the container when it exits
```